# How do I find the debian package name of a python module

Tags: python, apt

I learning python, and I keep finding new modules that I want to play with but aren't installed by default. Since I'm using Ubuntu, I know that all I need to do is to run apt-get with the correct package name.

The question is how do I find out what the apt package name is for a particular module? Is there an easy way to look it up?

Right now I am looking for the package for the "ipaddress" module.

```
ImportError: No module name ipaddress
```

Comment: It's better if you use (at least) `easy_install` to install the packages instead of the package manager (that's how I run my Ubuntu system - your first stage should be `easy_install pip`, then use `pip install <package>` onwards) - as Ubuntu won't always have the packages you're after - only main ones...

Comment: er, this is not a done deal.  Some people, like yourself, prefer the latest and greatest version.  Others prefer the convenience and easy  uninstall of a prebuilt package

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-cache search ipaddress | grep python
```

Is a good place to start.  Many modules are called "name-python"